# sorting table based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

i have to sort the employees in the EMPLOYEE table by the following rule: when their department is SALES, sort by experience, otherwise sort by SALARY

[image]

this is what i have tried :

```
select FNAME||' '||LNAME as emp_name,salary,HIRE_DATE from employee 
where dept_id=(select dept_id from department where name='SALES') order by HIRE_DATE asc;
UNION
select FNAME||' '||LNAME as emp_name,salary,HIRE_DATE from employee
where dept_id NOT IN (select dept_id from department where name='SALES') order by salary desc;
```

which throws an error because of two orders i think. Any solutions?

Comment: So you want to display the ones from sales first and then the rest?

Comment: display order is not important: sales can come first or after the others, the employees within sales should be sorted on experience and the employees from other departments should be sorted based on salary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select FNAME||' '||LNAME as emp_name,salary,HIRE_DATE from employee  E
join department D
on E.dept_id=D.dept_id
 order by (case when D.name='SALES' then HIRE_DATE end),
           (case when D.name<>'SALES' then salary end) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Sales department is displayed first, sorted by hire_date. Other departments are displayed next ordered by salary.

```
select FNAME||' '||LNAME as emp_name,salary,HIRE_DATE 
  from employee
 inner join department
    on employee.dept_id = department.dept_id
 order by
 -- Sales department is on top. Swap 0 and 1 if you want sales on bottom
       case when department.name = 'SALES'
            then 0
            else 1
       end,
 -- And employees are sorted by hire_date
       case when department.name = 'SALES'
            then employee.HIRE_DATE
            else null
       end,
 -- Employees from other departments are sorted by salary
       employee.Salary desc
```

Comment: nice solution, though a little long.

Comment: @ganducoder Thanks. This one divides departments to two groups; i thought that you want it that way, with sales on top and rest afterwards. That's why (and my habit of breaking lines for readability) it's a bit longer :-)

Answer (score 1):

use decode:

```
SELECT   fname || ' ' || lname AS emp_name
        ,salary
        ,hire_date
    FROM employee e
        ,department d
   WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id
ORDER BY decode(d.name,'SALES',experience,salary)
;
```

see also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afa6f/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.fname||' '||e.lname as emp_name, e.salary, e.hire_date
FROM employee e, department d
WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id 
ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN d.name ='SALES' then
hire_date ASC
ELSE
salary DESC
END
```

OK. Apologies, try this - probably been answered already tho.

Comment: this i what i  tried which throws an error. cant have two orders in one table/